# How do I delete IO80211Family.kext on macOS Mojave?

Tags: wifi, mojave

I am trying to disable WiFi on this machine by deleting /System/Library/Extensions/IO80211Family.kext. (I have backed the file up.)

If I try to delete IO80211Family.kext through Finder, I get an error "'IO80211Family.kext' can't be modified or deleted because it's required by macOS."

If I try to delete IO80211Family.kext using rm -r or rmdir from Terminal, I get an error "Operation not permitted." If I do sudo rm -r or sudo rmdir, I get the same error. It was suggested on one site that I give Terminal "full disk access" in my Systems Preferences. But I tried that, too, to no avail.

I've tried to change the file permissions of IO80211Family.kext with sudo chmod, but I get the same "Operation not permitted" error.

Another site suggested deleting IO80211Family.kext from Terminal in Recovery Mode. But the file doesn't seem to exist when I boot in Recovery Mode. (IO80211Family.kext doesn't appear when I use "ls" on the "/System/Library/Extensions" folder in Recovery Mode, but it does appear when I use the "ls" command after booting my machine normally.)

I wasn't able to find any advice online for deleting IO80211Family.kext beyond everything I tried above that hasn't worked. How can I delete this folder?

Comment: In Recovery Mode the regular system volume's Extensions folder can be found here: `/Volumes/name_of_regular_boot_volume/System/Library/Extensions/` with *name_of_regular_boot_volume* often `.../Macintosh\ HD/...`!

Comment: This is an odd way of disabling WiFi and sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is the problem that you having that requires disabling of the WiFi?

Comment: @klanomath I was able to solve my problem by navigating to the folder you suggested in Terminal in Recovery Mode. Thanks!

Comment: @Allan I literally just want to disable WiFi on my machine. There isn't an underlying technical problem that requires I do so.

Comment: Why not just turn it off?